# Angular js get input value issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get a value from hidden input by angular js. but the result come `undefined`. My code is

```js
var app = angular.module('newApp',[]);
app.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.save = function(marks){
         alert(marks);
      }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="newApp">
    <div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="marks" value="7">
     <button ng-click="save(marks)">Show</button>
     <br>
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="marks" value="2">
     <button ng-click="save(marks)">Show</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Actually your code example doesnt make much sense. You never declared the "id" on scope, you never change it and I cannot understand what is the whole logic of that example. Maybe better example would help you to solve the problem

Comment: simple I want to get previous hidden input value of the button

Comment: Still doesnt make sense... if you know what the value will be you can just do `ng-click="save(7)"` if the value is changing over time (probably by some ajax requests) then you change it in your controller `$scope.id=7;` and change will reflect in your view thanks to double-binding. BUT all inputs will change tot he same value - hence I am saying the example doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Your id-value isn't defined until you define it either directly in the scope or async by typing values into an input-field. ng-model basically binds to keyup-events, before it tries to define the scope-variable. Until then both of your input-field reads the value from an undeclared variable (undefined) and so does your save-function :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using hidden field, there is no point of having two-way data binding. Therefore, ng-model is not supported for hidden fields.

Here's the [github link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2574) for further reading.